# How to write Mongodb reduce function

Tags: mongodb-query

I am trying to write the a reduce function for the following map function in mongodb. The goal of this to returns the total value of all orders

```
String mapfn="function(){ var sum = 0;" +
        "for var i=0; i< this.order.length; i++" +
        " sum += this.orders[i].total;" + 
        "emit(\"totalOfAllOrders\",sum);}";
```

I am new to Mongodb and Im quite unsure how to go about writing the reduce function

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my issue. Turns out I had some syntax errors in the map function.
for reduce I was able to get the sum by using

```js
String reducefn ="function(key, items){ return Array.sum(items);}";
```